# Discord.js roles.create return role id

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, node-modules

when using `guild.roles.create({data: {some data}})`, the role is created. but i'd like it to return the role id to give it automatically  to a user, do any of you have on idea on how to do that.

by default, it returns a promise 
I also don't care if it stores the id into a variable instead of returning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make use of the promise to get the `role id`

```
guild.roles.create({
  data: {some data}
})
 .then(role => console.log(role.id))
 .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The create function returns a promise which resolve to a Role Object, Here's [more](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=create)

Answer (score 1):

We could very easily use a `.then()` function to get the role object we've just created and use it in order to find the brand new role's id:

```
guild.roles.create({
  // Data here
}).then(role => {
  member.roles.add(role.id) 
  // Just letting you know that it's also not required to get the ID in order to add the role.
  // We could've at the same time just done 'member.roles.add(role)'
})
```